# Chatting Activity via SMS Android Application

Tags: java, android, sms, chat

I'm trying to develop an application that allows users to chat with each other via sms..

I created an activity that sends and receives sms, but I don't know how can I make their chatting moving up (as in SMS messages in iPhone it seems like chatting page),

All I did is make the msg in edit text and receives it in textview ... 
actually i don't know what's the name of this thing to make search ... 
can anyone inform me what's the name of this technique!!!

I'm really confused ='.

Comment: Scroll or scrolling is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @Sparky thanks, but I meant how can I make their words go up, if i wrote any msg it still in the edit text hope u got me :"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would probably do in your case is implement the chat history as a `ListView`, sorted by entry timestamp.  When you send or receive new messages, just add them via your `ContentProvider` and tell the `ListView` to scroll to the bottom position.  It's a more code, but [examples](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) exist, and it's more flexible than hacking up a `TextView`.

Comment: can you help me please i wrote the code but I still have problem

Comment: I suggest you frame your problem as a new question on SO that describes specifically what doesn't work, then link to it from here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121751/sms-chatting-application-android  please take look at this !